ACS Video Call Recording servercallId API Error
I developed a project that can make video calls with the "QuickStart: Add 1:1 video calling" and "Rooms Call". When I access the Call Id value from this project and use it in the API, I get this error;
Invalid join identity, cannot join call. Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: 8527
Content:
{“error”:{“code”:“8527”,“message”:“Invalid join identity, cannot join call.”}}



Example call id: 34117f27-6459-4826-9v44-756rdde1c313
[HttpGet("StartRecording")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StartRecordingAsync([FromQuery] string serverCallId)
{
    try
    {
        _serverCallId = serverCallId ?? _client.GetCallConnection(_callConnectionId).GetCallConnectionProperties().Value.ServerCallId;

        StartRecordingOptions recordingOptions = new StartRecordingOptions(new ServerCallLocator(_serverCallId))
        {
            RecordingContent = RecordingContent.Audio,
            RecordingChannel = RecordingChannel.Unmixed,
            RecordingFormat = RecordingFormat.Wav,
        };

        var callRecording = _client.GetCallRecording();
        var response = await callRecording.StartAsync(recordingOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

        _recordingId = response.Value.RecordingId;
        return Ok($"RecordingId: {_recordingId}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}

Although I am using the original code without making many changes, this issue persists.
CallRecording API
QuickStart: Add 1:1 video calling to your app
What could I be doing wrong? I applied all the articles and solution suggestions but I couldn’t get a result.Despite having an active video call, I keep encountering the error Invalid join identity, cannot join call.

Please share the code in text format.

Although I am using the original code without making many changes, this issue persists. However, I did an update.

I have tried using your code, but there is a problem with the Wav format when using RecordingStateCallbackUri after wav. By calling callAutomationClient with Azure Storage, I was able to join the call.

The direct way to join a received call event is by using AnswerCallAsync(options) to get answer_result. You can then use answer_result.SuccessResult.ServerCallId to start the call recording.

For more details, refer to this MSDOC.
Also, refer to this git
for information on the recording status and how to download it.

I tried using your code even I got the same error .
Use RecordingStateCallbackUri after specifying Wav.
I have refered this MSDOC to configure call recording and make sure call should be active no need add
serverCallIdin get Description.

Below code is to receive recordingId during initiation of the call .
 RecordingFormat = RecordingFormat.Wav, 
    RecordingStateCallbackUri = new Uri(_configuration["CallbackUri"])  



The alternate direct way to join a received call event is by using AnswerCallAsync(options) to get answer_result. You can then use ServerCallId to start the call recording.
if (answer_result.IsSuccess)  
{  
  
CallLocator callLocator = new ServerCallLocator(answer_result.SuccessResult.ServerCallId);  
.....
......
}



For more details, refer to this GitHub repository for information on recording status and how to download it
Output:


Thank you for your response, Naveen. I am using tokens and user IDs for Voice and Video calling (VOIP) to create video calls. Do I still need to use a phone number for these processes? I don’t understand why a phone number is needed.

and what kind of value should be used for the CallbackUri?

For steering calls/voice calls require phone as per sample code in this link. For Video calling video required user_token and user ID as per this links.

The   Voice/Videocall should be active for recording code to work. CallbackUri will like this EndpointofCommunicationService/api/callbacks
